# Return First Character of each word in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a string with Names and I want to convert them to Initials. E.g:

- John White -> JW
- John P White -> JPW

I am looking for a suggesting on how best to do this. I have researched using `split()` and looked here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp but could not find a good example of how to target and return first letter when I don't know the char to look for.

My string looks like this

```
<a href="#">John White</a>
```

and I want to change to this

```
<a href="#">JW</a>
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Split by space to get words in array, then loop and extract the first letter by index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first letter of each word in a string, in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279859/get-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), Here's an [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/uST28/)

```js
var myStr = "John P White";
var matches = myStr.match(/\b(\w)/g);
console.log(matches.join(''));
```

`\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`

> 1st Capturing Group (`\w`)
>
> > `\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
>
> Global pattern flags
>
> > `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

For better explanation visit [**here**](http://regex101.com/r/lB4dZ4)

Comment: this breaks for names with a apostrophe or a hyphen

Comment: how can we limit this to return only 2 characters?

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = "John P White";

function initials(value){
    var result = "";
    var tokens = value.split(/\s/);
    for(var i =0; i < tokens.length; i++){
      result += tokens[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    }
    return result;
}

initials(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var words = $('a').text().split(' ');
var text = '';
$.each(words, function () {
    text +=  this.substring(0, 1);
});
$('a').text(text);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KfbET/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var name = "John P White",
    data = name.split(' '), output = "";

for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    output += data[i].substring(0,1);
}

alert(output);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz7je/)</kbd>

Comment: I think this is the best answer.. It handles hyphenated words

Answer (score 1):

Please find below the answer by splitting the string by space and getting the first letter and later joining those first letters together

```js
let example_one='John White';
example_one=example_one.split(' ').map(word=>word[0]).join('');
console.log(example_one);

let example_two='John P White';
example_two=example_two.split(' ').map(word=>word[0]).join('');
console.log(example_two);
```

Comment: Please add some words on how this solves the problem to avoid blind-copying

Answer (score 0):

With delimiter as `space` you can split the names and put it into an Array. And then you can take the first index of each element inside the Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to match anything that's not an uppercase letter and then simply remove it.

```
<a href="#">John White</a>
<a href="#">John P Brown</a>

$('a').each(function(){
    var initials = $(this).text().replace(/[^A-Z]/g, "");
    $(this).text(initials);
});
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/vFtEf/)**