# Javascript Return the location of the first letter of each word in a string using a loop

Tags: javascript, string, loops

Having trouble coming up with code doing this.

So for example here is my string.
    var str = "Hello how are you today?";

How would I manipulate this string to return the position of the first letter of each word using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will give you the result with less complicated code and a single loop

```js
function foo(str) {
  var pos = [];
  var words = str.split(' ');
  pos.push(1);
  var prevWordPos;
  for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    prevWordPos = pos[i - 1] + words[i - 1].length;
    pos.push((str.indexOf(words[i], prevWordPos) + 1));
  }
  return pos;
}
```

Comment: EDITED for better readability of the code. Thanks @Anders Anderson

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to search a regular expression `\b\w` and collect <strike>`match.start()`</strike> `match.index` for each match. Loop while there's matches.

EDIT: wrong language. lol.

Comment: *from time–to–time* should probably be seen as 4 words, not two. Up to the OP to decide what represents a word boundary I suppose. ;-).

Comment: @RobG: True. You can get to other definitions of "word" by using appropriate lookbehind assertions instead of "word boundary".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp `replace` passing a function instead of a replacement string, this will call the function for each match:

```
str.replace(/[^ ]+/g, function(match, pos) {
    console.log("Word " + match + " starts at position " + pos);
});
```

The regexp meaning is:

- `[^ ]`: anything excluding space
- `+`: one or more times
- "g" option: not only first match, but each of them

in other words the function will be called with sequences of non-spaces. Of course you can define what you consider a "word" differently.

Comment: I don't really understand this line of code too well.
in str.replace(/[^ ] +/g. I understand the '+' concatenates and the '/g' is to search globally in the string. what does [^ ] do?  and also, is there more code in here that is supposed to return the position of the first letter in each word?

Answer (score 0):

You should search for a question before asking it in case it's already been asked and answered.
[Get first letter of each word in a string, in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279859/get-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: The OP wants the position of the letters, not to concatenate them.

Comment: Yup. looking for how to find position of the first letter of each word.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Solution with two Loops, i hope that is close enough ;)

```js
var starts = [];
var str = "How are you doing today?";
//var count = 0;
var orgStr = str;
while (str.indexOf(" ") > 0) {
    if (starts.length > 0) {       
        starts.push(starts[starts.length - 1] + str.indexOf(" ") +1);
    } else {
        starts.push(1);
        starts.push(str.indexOf(" ") +2);
        //alert(str);
    }
    str = str.substring(str.indexOf(" ") + 1);
}
for (var i = 0; i < starts.length; i++) {
    alert(starts[i] + ": " + orgStr.substring(starts[i]-1,starts[i]))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
After trying to think about this for hours, this helped tremendously. It's amazing how reading the code is so much easier than writing it. Hopefully, I can keep practicing it and come up with it easier and easier!

Comment: You're welcome.
You should definately take a look at the answer by @Avishek.
It's way more beautiful than mine, eventhough i think it's harde to read :D