# Is it possible to get only the first letter of what is written in the input?

Tags: javascript, input

I want to get only the first letter of what is written in the input. Can help me?

```
<input id="texte" type="text" placeholder="type your name here" oninput="copyText('texte', 'text')">
<div id="text">first letter here</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function copyText(texteId, text1Id) {
  var data = document.getElementById(texteId).value;
  document.getElementById(text1Id).innerHTML = data;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe try `data.charAt(0);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first letter of each word in a string, in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279859/get-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @michael-myers perhaps you should still to the Java and C questions, like you're used to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can split the variable `data` as an array:

```js
function copyText(texteId, text1Id) {
  var data = document.getElementById(texteId).value[0];
  document.getElementById(text1Id).innerHTML = data;
}
```

```html
<input id="texte" type="text" placeholder="type your name here" oninput="copyText('texte', 'text')">
<div id="text">first letter here</div>
```

Use `[number]` to get the value at some point.

Or you could use the [`slice()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) function:

```js
function copyText(texteId, text1Id) {
  var data = document.getElementById(texteId).value;
  document.getElementById(text1Id).innerHTML = data.slice(0,1);
}
```

```html
<input id="texte" type="text" placeholder="type your name here" oninput="copyText('texte', 'text')">
<div id="text">first letter here</div>
```

Or as suggested in the other answer [`charAt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp).

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra No problem at all. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use charAt(0) to get the first character:

```js
function copyText(inputId,displayId) {
  var data = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
  var firstLetter = data.charAt(0);
  document.getElementById(displayId).innerHTML = "The first letter is: " + firstLetter;
}
```

```html
<label for ="texte">Type your name here</label>
<input id="texte" type="text" onkeyup="copyText('texte','text')">
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function copyText( texteId, text1Id ) {
  var d = document;
  d.g = d.getElementById;
  var data = d.g( texteId ).value[0];
  d.g( text1Id ).innerHTML = data;
}
```

```html
<input id="texte" type="text" placeholder="type your name here" oninput="copyText('texte', 'text')">
<div id="text">first letter here</div>
```

In JavaScript you may treat a string as if it were an array.  So by specifying the zeroeth index of value, the code grabs the first letter and that becomes the content of the div with the id of "text" using that element's innerHTML property.

Answer (score 2):

```
const input = document.querySelector('#texte');
const text = document.querySelector('#text');

// keydown and keyup are alternate events
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  text.innerHTML = this.value[0];
});
```